# How to receive inline styles and classes in a component

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a custom Container component and I would like to be able to receive inline styling and classes applied to this component. The component syntax:

```
const Container = ({ children }) => {
  return <div  className={classes.container}>{children}</div>;
};
```

When using it I would like for example to add inline styles:

```
<Container style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
  <p>hello</p>
</Container>
```

Or classes:

```
<Container className={classes.aClass}>
  <p>hello</p>
</Container>
```

But what is the correct syntax in Container component to receive those? I'm sorry I know that this is a basic question, it was probably asked before but I cannot find it and probably I don't search with the right terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive the style as props and pass it to the container's `div` element

```
const Container = ({ children, style }) => {
  return (
    <div 
      className={classes.container}
      style={style}
    >
      {children}
    </div>;
  );
};
```

For CSS classes, you will have to merge your existing classes with the classes passed by users. For that, I would recommend a tiny library like [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) which helps us combine with ease

```
import clsx from "clsx"

const Container = ({ children, style, className }) => {
  return (
    <div 
      className={clsx(classes.container, className)}
      style={style}
    >
      {children}
    </div>;
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, would you know how can I receive classNames?

Comment: Thank you very much I'll check that library out

Answer (score 1):

```
<Container color="red"}>
  <p>hello</p>
</Container>
const Container = (props) => {
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }}>>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

Pass styles as props and use it in container